# Checking if IP address is real - Getting ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '192.168.0.105'

Tags: python, valueerror, python-sockets

I am attempting to make a chat room for a class project (I have stumped my teacher and he has given me permission to use any sources at my disposal, including asking Stack Overflow which some teachers don't allow). Before the user gets to the chatroom itself I want to make sure the IP address they want is valid. I have gotten my little section of code that checks the IP address from this site and it helped slightly.

[Here's my code so far (sorry it's a link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKUfw.png)

When I run it and input my own IP address (just so I know it is an actual IP address), I get the following error message;

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '192.168.0.105'

This is only the start of my code and I am hoping to solve it rather quickly, so any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Code belongs in your question, not as a picture.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in your user input line:

```
int('192.168.0.105')
```

Will throw an error because you can't convert an IP address to an integer, an IP address is *not* an integer.

The function [`socket.inet_aton()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_aton) takes:

> an IPv4 address from dotted-quad string format (for example, ‘123.45.67.89’)

So just remove the conversion to `int` and your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can not type cast string which contains dot which is causing error. Just remove type casting i.e. `int()` prior to `input()`. `inet_aton()` takes care of ip validation internally.

code:

```
import socket
userip = input("enter ip addr")
try:
    socket.inet_aton(userip)
except socket.error:
    print("invalid ip")
```